# How to iterate through a list of strings with different lengths?

Tags: python, string, list

Suppose I have

`lists = ["ABC","AC","CCCC","BC"]`

I want a new list where items in my new list are grouped by position based on `lists` meaning for each string in the list take the position 0("ABC" position 0 is "A") and make a string out of it.

`position = ["AACB","BCCC","CC","C"]`

I try:

`for i in range(0,4):
    want = [lists[i] for stuff in lists]`

and I get

`IndexError: string index out of range`

Which makes sense because all the strings are different size. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Please clarify it, so that I can help.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do but the error you getting is caused by trying to access lists[2] (the third item) in a 2 item list.

Comment: I assume that if you had a third string BC, your expected output is ["AAB", "BBC", "C"]?

Comment: What is the desired output for `["ABC","AC","BCD"]`?

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `['AA', 'BC', 'C']`?

Comment: @dawg the desired output there would be ["AAB","BCC","CD"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want this:

```
import itertools
lists = ["ABC","AC","CCCC","BC"]
position = map(''.join,itertools.izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=''))
```

and you get:

```
['AACB', 'BCCC', 'CC', 'C']
```

edit: now with the new example...

Comment: What the OP wants, and what he says he wants, are sometimes two different things.

Comment: is there a way simpler way to do this without itertools?

Comment: @user2801122 way to look a gift horse in the mouth. Why not make your own attempt? For example, you could `try` on each input iterable and `pass` on `IndexError`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
>>> lists = ["ABC","AC","CCCC","BC"]
>>> [''.join([s[i:i+1] for s in lists]) for i, el in enumerate(lists)]
['AACB', 'BCCC', 'CC', 'C']
```

Using the slice notation prevents index errors on non-existing elements.